# Moving each file into its own directory

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a script where I have multiple files in a directory but I want to make a directory for each file with a particular extension(without the file extension in the directory name) and move each file into their own directory and then do something to each file in its respective directory.
 I'm really new to this so this is as far as I've gotten and it doesn't work so any help would be appreciated!

```
for file in *;
     do
        if  [ $file=[$.sff]] ; then
          mkdir ${$file/.sff/""/}
          mv $file ${file/.sff/""/}/
            fi
        for $file in $file/
              do { ......
            }
done
```

Comment: ${} has some special syntax, should look it up - im fairly certain it doesnt accept `""` as an empty string, simply leave it out. or you could go along with `$(echo $file|sed 's/\.sff//')`

Answer (score 2):

You do not want an if statement, or a case statement.  Just do:

```
die() { echo "$*" >&2; exit 1; }
for file in *; do
  dir=${file%.*}
  test -d $dir || mkdir $dir  # or just mkdir -p $dir
  test -f $dir && die "$dir exists and is a file!"
  mv $file $dir
done
for dir in *; do ...; done  # Do something in each directory
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in *.*
do
  dir=${file%.*}
  mkdir "$dir"
  newfile=$dir/$file
  mv "$file" "$newfile"
  ... do something with "$newfile"
done
```